# If else exist statement in select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Here are three tables where I want a query to select which filter/s will be expired in 7 next few days.
[image]

I have 2 columns called `filterExp` in the `Filter` table and `filterExpCustom` in the `FilterChange` table, the first is the default if the second is not empty.
All filters have an expiration value in the day terms but in some cases, some users want to change the expiration value for their own. So they can set `filterExpCustom` for specific customers and filters.

Here are some actual values to better understand:

**Filter**

```
INSERT [Filter] ([filterId], [filterName], [filterExp]) 
VALUES (1, N'pp', 6)
INSERT [Filter] ([filterId], [filterName], [filterExp]) 
VALUES (2, N'Carbonate', 5)
INSERT [Filter] ([filterId], [filterName], [filterExp]) 
VALUES (3, N'Carbon Block', 5)
INSERT [Filter] ([filterId], [filterName], [filterExp]) 
VALUES (4, N'Carbon Post', 12)
INSERT [Filter] ([filterId], [filterName], [filterExp]) 
VALUES (5, N'Mineral', 12)
```

**FilterChange**

```
INSERT [FilterChange] ([filterChnageId], [customerId], [filterId], [customerDeviceId], [filterChangeDate], [filterExpCustom]) 
VALUES (186, 3, 2, 65, CAST(N'2023-01-31' AS Date), 7)
INSERT [FilterChange] ([filterChnageId], [customerId], [filterId], [customerDeviceId], [filterChangeDate], [filterExpCustom]) 
VALUES (187, 3, 5, 65, CAST(N'2023-01-31' AS Date), NULL)
INSERT [FilterChange] ([filterChnageId], [customerId], [filterId], [customerDeviceId], [filterChangeDate], [filterExpCustom]) 
VALUES (188, 2, 3, 66, CAST(N'2023-02-01' AS Date), 10)
INSERT [FilterChange] ([filterChnageId], [customerId], [filterId], [customerDeviceId], [filterChangeDate], [filterExpCustom]) 
VALUES (189, 2, 3, 66, CAST(N'2023-02-01' AS Date), NULL)
```

Here is the query that I can get the expired filter/s from now until 7 days next:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FilterExpirationGetList]
  @userName BIGINT
AS
  DECLARE @InNextDays int
BEGIN
    SET @InNextDays = 7

  SELECT f.filterId,f.filterName, f.filterExp,
    fc.customerId, fc.customerDeviceId, fc.filterChangeDate, fc.filterExpCustom,
    c.fName, c.lName, c.cMobile, c.userName
   FROM FilterChange fc INNER JOIN
     Filter f  ON fc.filterId = f.filterId  INNER JOIN
     Customer c ON c.CustomerId = fc.customerId
   WHERE c.userName = @userName AND
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) 
    - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY,f.filterExp,fc.filterChangeDate)), 
    DATEADD(DAY,f.filterExp,fc.filterChangeDate))
          BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
           AND CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() + @InNextDays); 
END
```

**The problem with my query is I don't know how to select expired filters if `filterExpCustom` has some value but if it doesn't, the `filterExp` must be calculated in the query.**

Comment: Replace all occurences of `f.filterExp` with `coalesce(fc.filterExpCustom, f.filterExp)`.

Comment: Please don't use images, show the DDL as text.

Comment: What would be your expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps, you use ISNULL to get the correct day extension:

```sql
select *
from customer c
inner join FilterChange fc
 ON fc.customerID = fc.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Filter f
 ON f.filterID = fc.filterID
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, ISNULL(fc.filterExpCustom,filterExp), filterChangeDate) BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE())
```

I'm not sure what you do with customers where filters expired before today though. Your design seem lacking a sort of flag that says that filterchange is "superceeded" with another change.

Alternatively you can fetch only the latest filterchange per filter type where expiration dates is less than 7 days forward. I leave it as exercise to the reader

Comment: Nice job unraveling the original where logic and stripping it down to that which was actually needed.